# Use a class in another class

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

In my project, I kept all common methods in a file and named its class as `SandBox`. I am loading this file in `<head>`.

Now I need to use this `SandBox` class in another class which is page specific. The class name is `Home` class. I am loading this `Home` class just above `</body>`.

How should I use `SandBox` class in `Home` class?

I tried the below in my `Home` class where I can access methods of `SandBox` class only in `initialize` property but I need to access it in all methods of `Home` class without repeatedly declaring as `new SandBox()` in each method.

```
var PdClicksClass = Class.create();
PdClicksClass.prototype = {
    initialize : function(){
        var sb = new SandBox();
        sb.attachEvents(/* some arguments here */);
    },
    toggleReviewSection : function(e){
        //SandBox class methods should also use here
    },
    openImagePopup: function(e){
        //SandBox class methods should also use here    
    }
};

var projectDetails = new PdClicksClass();
```

PS: I don't think declaring `new SandBox()` in each method of `Home` class (*as I did in **initialize** above*) is efficient one though.

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Why do you think `new SandBox` is not "efficient" (whatever that means in this context)?

Comment: @FelixKling no problem.. but I need to access the methods related to `SandBox` class in my `Home` Class. `new SandBox` is efficient but using it again and again in all methods of `Home` class is not good I think. There must be some alternative.

Comment: If you want to access `sb` inside the other method, you have to declare it as a property of the object, not a local variable. If you want each `PdClicksClass` instance having its own `SandBox` instance, then that's what you have to do.

Comment: Maybe have a method that returns `sb`? Then call it from the home class? `var derp = PdClicksClass.getSandBox();` A better way would be a obj property though

Comment: @FelixKling ohh.. then I need to use it as `this.sb` in all methods right?

Comment: Yep. Whether you actually need to create an instance we don't know though since we don't know what actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @RUJordan that seems good way.. any small example? actually, I was thinking there might be something like `var projectDetails = new PdClicksClass(new SandBox());`..

Comment: @FelixKling Just curious, isn't there a way where I can use the `SandBox` class object without using `this` like `this.sb` in `Home` class? I mean I want to access it directly by just calling `sb`... if I do `var projectDetails = new PdClicksClass(new SandBox());`, I am getting the object in array of `arguments` but then I don't know how to store it in a variable `sb` so that I can use it in all the methods of `Home` class..

Comment: You'd still have to assign it to `this.sb`. Whether you pass the instance to the constructor or instantiated it inside the constructor doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @FelixKling hehe.. ok thanks.. I think what I am trying can be achieved using `Requirejs` (_done the same in my previous projects_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of an object property way I would do this

```
function PdClicksClass() {
    /* other class stuff here */
    this.sb = new Sandbox();
}

PdClicksClass.prototype = {
    getSandbox : function() {
        return this.sb;
    }
}
```

Or if encapsulation isn't an issue, simply call it by `PdClicksClass.sb`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var sb = //etc
```

You want to do

```
this._sb = //etc
```

Then you can refer to

```
this._sb
```

The underscore is often used in js as convention for private values.